# I need help on understading: Write a method, sum which takes an array of numbers and returns the sum of the numbers

Tags: ruby, sum

I've been studying ruby and have been taking some exercises to see how much I have learned and I've come across this:

Q: Write a method, sum which takes an array of numbers and returns the sum of the numbers.

The answer was provided for the problem but I don't understand why or how. I would like some help from anyone to explain them for me in simple terms so that I can understand this. Please keep in mind that I'm new to programming.  Thank you.

A:

```
def sum(nums)
  total = 0

  i = 0
  while i < nums.count
    total += nums[i]

    i += 1
  end

  # return total
  total
end
```

Comment: Who came up with this answer? It's not idiomatic Ruby.

Comment: which part is unclear to you?

Comment: @MarkThomas agreed it's not idiomatic Ruby, but if he/she is new to programming, it's best to start with the basics than to do shortcuts.

Comment: The provided answer relies on mutable variables, side-effects and loops, all of which cause a combinatorial explosion in the complexity of the state-space of the program, and thus are anything *but* basics, IMO. Plus, programming is about communication and this program doesn't clearly communicate the intent *at all*. Plus, it is non-idiomatic. Plus, it is a potential source for off-by-one errors. Plus, it needlessly runs in O(n^2) instead of O(n). It really *is* bad code and shouldn't be taught to anyone, *especially* beginners.

Comment: The idiomatic solution would be a fold over the array with addition as the combining function.  I learned about folds in high school math, so I think that qualifies as "basics". To a programming beginner `i = i + 1` makes absolutely no sense. They will just think "there is no such `i` which could possibly satisfy this equation." It might seem basic to you, but to a beginner, this is incredibly confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sum(nums)
  total = 0
  i = 0 # i is set to `0`, as in Ruby array is 0 based.i will point to the
        # first element in the array initially.
  while i < nums.count # loop to iterate through the array till the last index come.
    total += nums[i] # nums[i] is for accessing the element from the array at index i.
    # and adding the value of total in previous iteration to current element 
    # of the array at i(or to the initial value of total,if it is the first iteration).
    i += 1 # this move the i from current index to next index of the array.
  end

  # return total
  total
end
```

`i += 1` is called the syntactic sugar of `i=i+1`.Same is true for `total += nums[i]`.

Comment: Thank you so much, for this was the type of explanation i needed to understand the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let me add some comments to see if this helps...

```
def sum(nums)

  # initialize total to zero
  total = 0

  # initialize a counter to zero
  i = 0

  # while the counter is less than the size / count of the array...
  while i < nums.count

    # add the number at the array index of i to total
    # this can also be written:  total = total + nums[i]
    total += nums[i]

    # increment your counter, then loop
    i += 1
  end

  # return total
  total
end
```

Comment: Thank you.  This also further help me understand the answer but Arup nailed it on breaking it down.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this with ruby is

```
def sum (nums_array)
  nums_array.inject(:+)
end
```

Equivalently, you could use `reduce`, which is an alias for `inject`.

Inject iterates over your array cumulatively applying any binary operation to every element, returning the accumulator (in this case, the sum of all the elements). You could also do something like

```
  nums_array.inject(:-)  
  nums_array.inject(:*)
  nums_array.inject(:%)
```

and etc.

The best place to test any Ruby method is in IRB or PRY on the command line, or, if you'd rather use something with a GUI and are working on a Mac, [CodeRunner](http://krillapps.com/coderunner/) is great.

For more on inject / reduce (or any method you come across), the [ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) are a great resource.

Answer (score 1):

This is *horrible*. Whoever wrote doesn't understand the first thing about Ruby. He doesn't even understand much of programming, apparently. Just forget about it.

This is how a Rubyist or pretty much any other programmer would solve that problem:

```
def sum(nums)
  nums.inject(0, :+)
end
```

Unlike the code that was provided to you, this doesn't use any concepts outside of some basic math. (Fold and Addition.)

Comment: Would you mind explaining this please?  I tried to google .inject and :+, but no luck on anything to make sense of this. How do I run this?  Thank you